# MacOS Ventura confuses monitors

Tags: macos, mac, display, hdmi, displayport

I have a M2 Mac Mini Pro running Ventura 13.2.1 connected to three Samsung LU28R55 monitors. One is connected with a USB-C to Display Port cable, one is connected via an HDMI cable, and one is connected with a USC-C to HDMI cable. Both of the HDMI connections are to HDMI-2 on the target monitor.

I have issues where the wallpaper resets to default on all or some of the desktops upon reboot, and the arrangement of the display changes. All the displays show up in MacOS as LU28R55(1), LU28R55(2), LU28R55(3), and the number in parentheses changes from day to day.

One of the three monitors (using Display Port) is shared with other devices but most often set to the Mac. The other two are also shared with other devices, mainly my work laptop, and are most often used with the work laptop, just active on the Mac after hours.

So I said I see what's going on here, MacOS is getting confused because they're all the same model and all the same name, let me give them distinct names. Tried doing that with SwitchResX but it didn't work, the name doesn't change.

Installed BetterDisplay and tried to name the monitors LU28R55_LEFT, LU28R55_CENTER, and LU28R55_RIGHT. That worked -- sort of. The monitor on DisplayPort has had its name changed. The two on HDMI will rename, but MacOS is still confusing them -- I end up with LU28R55_RIGHT(1) and LU28R55_RIGHT(2).

Tried renaming with just one of the monitors powered on, but that does not help. As soon as I connect the other one the number in parentheses pops right on there.

I have **not** tried using HDMI-1 on one monitor and HDMI-2 on another as it's really difficult to manage the cable connections on these monitors, the ergonomics of the ports are awful.

One thing I have noticed using BetterDisplay is that there is a value called "Serial" on both monitors that is listed first in the properties and is identical. There is also a UUID which is unique. There is an EDID Serial Number consisting of two values -- the first is identical between the two monitors, the second is not, and appears to match the alphanumeric serial number listed later in the properties. This alphanumeric serial number is also unique for the two.

Any ideas?

Is there a plist somewhere I can edit, or just NUKE, to fix this?

Have I just flown too close to the sun having three identical 4k monitors hooked to a Mac Mini?

Comment: Swapped HDMI's, didn't help.

Comment: Really weird thing is if I use BetterDisplay to adjust the brightness on one of the confused monitors, the one I intended to adjust dims first, then THE OTHER MONITOR STARTS TO DIM! First monitor goes completely dark around 50% and then the other one starts and is black by 0%.

Comment: Also observed that the [CGDirectDisplayID], [tag], and [Service Port] are unique between the two monitors but [Configuration ID] is **not**.